# NoMethodError rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have user and seeker_info models in my rails 4 app, and the relationship between these two models is one-to-one that is user has_one seeker_info.user has to fill up his seeker_info after sign up.i have image field in my seeker_info model and i am displaying user's image on my page's header part before user's name. but after sign up i am getting below error. the problem is that after sign up, seeker_info model is empty , because only after successful sign up user can fill his seeker_info details.

```
undefined method `image' for nil : Nil Class
```

this is my code

```
<%= image_tag current_user.seeker_info.image_url.to_s, :class=>"img-profile" if current_user.seeker_info.image? %>
```

Comment: `if current_user.seeker_info && current_user.seeker_info.image?`

Comment: Usually It is preferred to use a decorator here. You have to create a `UserDecorator` and get the `image_url` from there. It will allow you to separate the view concerns from your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
undefined method `image' for nil : Nil Class
```

This error means that you are calling a method `image` on a `nil` object.

Modify the condition to check if both `seeker_info` and `seeker_info.image` is present.

```
if current_user.seeker_info && current_user.seeker_info.image?
```